# Javascript - How to append user input to a new list item in a form. (how to add a record)

Tags: javascript, forms, appendchild, createelement

I am trying to create a to do list using just javascript.

I want users to be able to add tasks to their to do list, and then sort by priority value, being low,medium,or high. I am appending the user input but not in the format I desire. I would like to output a new record containing inside an `<li>` element a new label, new checkBox input, and new select field for Priority.

I am starting to get lost and believe I am over complicating the scripting, does anyone have any suggestions on how to create the new elements and append them to my `<ul>`?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title>Page title</title>
<style type="text/css">

             #myForm{width: 600px; background: red;}

             #listContent{clear:both}

             legend h3{background:blue; margin-top: 30px;}

             #labels {margin-left: 70px; width:690px;}
             .listLabels{margin-right: 145px; font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; font-size: 20px;}

             ul {display: block; width: 500px;  background:blue;}

             li{clear: both; width: 600px; background: purple; list-style-type: none; padding: 2em 2em;}

             .label{display:block; float:left; width: 150px;}

             .checkBox{display: block; float: left; margin-left: 55px; width: 100px; color: green;}

             .selectPriority{display: block; width: 80px; float: right; color: blue;}

       #addMoreContent{clear:both;}

             .newLabel{display:block; float:left; width: 100px;}

             .inputText{display: block; width: 300px; float: left;}

             .addButton{display:block; width: 60px; }            

             #addSection{position: relative; width: 600px; background: brown; bottom:60px; left: 40px; padding-right: 50px; text-align:right;}

             target          



</style>
<script language="javascript">

var counter = 0;

function addNewItem(){
// Target the user input
     var UserInput = document.getElementById('userInputText').value;
     var UserInputString = UserInput.toString();
        if (UserInputString==""){
//Display error if field is left blank
        alert('Please add an item to the To-Do list.');
        }
//Do this if user input is detected
else {
          function CreateLiElement() {  

      var liElement = document.createElement("li");  
            var labelElement = document.createElement("label");
      var checkBoxElement = document.createElement("input");
            var selectElement = document.createElement ("select");
            var optionElement = document.createElement ("option");
            var userOption = document.getElementById ("userOption");  

      labelElement.setAttribute('class', 'label');
      checkBoxElement.setAttribute('type', 'checkBox')
            checkBoxElement.setAttribute('class','checkBox');
            selectElement.setAttribute('class','selectPriority')
            selectElement.setAttribute('name','priority')
            optionElement.setAttribute('value',userOption)   

      liElementItems = labelElement, checkBoxElement, selectElement, optionElement, userOption;  
      document.body.appendChild(liElementItems);  

      }  

          var y=document.getElementById('targetAdd')
      // variable x gets the innerhtml of the element above
      var x=y.innerHTML
      // alert just shows it on the screen. You can do whatever you want with x
      alert(x);

            alert('the function is complete');
            alert(UserInputString);


          var element = document.createElement('label'.className='label');
            var answer = document.createTextNode(UserInputString);
            alert(element)
            document.getElementById("listItems").appendChild(element).className=('label');
            document.getElementById("listItems").appendChild(answer);
            alert('the function is complete');
        }


        /*
            var Priority = new Array(3);
      Priority[0] = "High";
      Priority[1] = "Medium";
      Priority[2] = "Low";
            */
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

            <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="#" method="POST">
                        <fieldset>
                                    <div id="listContent">                                  
                                                <legend><h3>My Tasks</h3></legend>
                                                     <div id="labels">
                                                                <span class="listLabels"><strong>To-Do</strong></span>
                                                                <span class="listLabels"><strong>Completed</strong></span>
                                                                <span class="listLabels"><strong>Priority</strong></span>
                                                     </div>

                                                        <ul id="listItems" class="listItems"><!-- begin list items -->

                                                                <li>
                                                                    <label class="label">Make Iced Coffee</label>
                                                                    <input class="checkBox" type="checkBox" name="list1" id="list1" />
                                                                    <select class="selectPriority" name="priority">
                                                                                    <option value="low">Low</option>
                                                                                    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                                                                                    <option value="high">High</option>
                                                                  </select>
                                                                </li>

                                                            <li>
                                                                <label class="label">Go take the dog for a run</label>
                                                                <input  class="checkBox" type="checkBox" name="list2" id="list2" />
                                                                    <select class="selectPriority" name="priority">
                                                                                    <option value="low">Low</option>
                                                                                    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                                                                                    <option value="high">High</option>
                                                                  </select>
                                                            </li>

                                                            <li>
                                                                <label class="label">Apply for Jobs</label>
                                                                <input class="checkBox"  type="checkBox" name="list3" id="list3" />
                                                                    <select class="selectPriority" name="priority">
                                                                                    <option value="low">Low</option>
                                                                                    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                                                                                    <option value="high">High</option>
                                                                  </select>
                                                            </li>

                                                            <li>
                                                                <label class="label">Work on JavaScript project</label>
                                                                <input class="checkBox" type="checkBox" name="list4" id="list4" />
                                                                    <select class="selectPriority" name="priority">
                                                                                    <option value="low">Low</option>
                                                                                    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                                                                                    <option value="high">High</option>
                                                                  </select>
                                                            </li>

                                                    </ul><!-- end list items -->
                                    </div><!-- end list content -->

                                    <div id="addMoreContent"
                                                <legend><h3>Add Task</h3></legend>
                                                        <ul>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <label class="newLabel" for="addTask">New Task:</label>
                                                                    <div id="targetAdd">
                                                                    <input id="userInputText" class="inputText" type="text" />
                                                                    <select id="userOption" class="selectPriority" name="priority">
                                                                                    <option value="low">Low</option>
                                                                                    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                                                                                    <option value="high">High</option>
                                                                  </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <div id="addSection">
                                                        <button id="addItem"  class="addButton" type="button" onClick="addNewItem()">Add</button>
                                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- end add Content section -->
                        </fieldset>
            </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I ask why you are not using jQuery?

Comment: because i put so much effort into this haha.. trying to understand javascript methods. I am just beginning to learn jQuery and do not kno how to script well with it yet. Would it be much less complicated?

Comment: @Todd, for future questions please consider making smaller sample (it is harder with HTML than just JavaScript alone, but may help you understand issue too). Also look at formatting sample so at least it does not need horizontal scroll (i.e. remove extra spaces, use tab=2 spaces if possible). And clean out unrealated/unneded comments (including ones like `// variable x gets the innerhtml of the element above` that repeat code: `var x=y.innerHTML`).

Answer (score 0):

`function appendToList(elementLI, ul){ if(elementLI)elementLI.appendChild(ul); }`

`... onclick -> appendToList(myLIST, document.createElement('ul, 'etc'))`

where 'etc' is the options you are given from the text box inter alia...